# Async sftp file transfer with Jsch?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, asynchronous

Is there a way to do asynchronous sftp file transfer with Jsch without having to manage your own threads?

I see there is a
[SftpProgressMonitor](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html) to monitor the progress but it just provides a callback.

I'm looking for something similar to Java's `AsynchronousFileChannel` write method:

[public abstract Future write(ByteBuffer src, long position)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long-)

Which library provides async sftp transfer?

Comment: There's no support for asynchronous transfers in JSch.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Neither there seems to be such support in any of the other free Java sftp libraries that I investigated. Sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem performing the transfer asynchronously using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)(take a look at `runAsync` and `supplyAsync` methods).

The class also offers methods to combine or chain multiple futures together with methods like: `CompletableFuture.allOf`, `CompletableFuture.thenCompose`, etc...

Comment: or just Mono.fromCallable()